# Get the raw XML of params in a WCF service implementation

Tags: wcf, linq-to-xml

I'm setting up a new .NET 4.0 WCF service with a method (operation) that takes strongly typed XSD generated data types as parameters. This makes things clean and tidy for the client - the client can work with strong types and not have to think about XML.

However, in the implementation of the WCF service, I would prefer to deal with the parameter data as XML documents (LINQ XDocument) instead of the deserialized object types. It's nice that WCF will deserialize to explicit types, but for my generic algorithm it's more convenient and more flexible to deal with the xml documents instead, primarily because the incoming data is polymorphic.

I know I can just take the parameter objects and serialize them back down to XML, but this seems wasteful.

I understand that I could probably replace the strongly typed params with XElement to get what I want for implementation convenience, but this will lose the benefits of strong typing (compiler checks, intellisense, self documentation) for the client.

Is there any way to tell WCF that in my service implementation I don't need the parameter objects deserialized, that I want them as XML instead?

Or, is there a way to access the raw XML of the params as they were prior to WCF deserializing them into objects? If I can't prevent WCF from spending time deserializing the objects at least this would avoid the cost of reserializing them back to XML.

Comment: I will still think is it really worth the hassle, why not to speed up serailization and deserilazation.

Comment: @SurjitSamra I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that WCF isn't worth the hassle, or my interest in accessing the raw XML isn't worth the hassle?  I can't do anything about speeding up serialization or deserialization, other than to avoid unnecessary round trips.

Comment: sorry I was not clear in my comment I actually mean accessing raw XML is worth the hassle? WCF is well worth of every hassle :), I recently migrated over 10 year old .NET remoting distrubuted system in WCF , there is heavy custom serialization / deserialization to speed up everything , If you use some sort of injections eg one marc_s said in his ans then you will find how long acutally everything takes, in my case I was happy that deserialization only took <30 ms.

Comment: Working with the raw XML with Linq is worth the hassle when I'm only interested in certain portions of the XML and there are multiple XML objects / XSD data types that can be sent. The explicit data types don't behave polymorphically, but with Linq+XML I can achieve polymorphism over the data - use one algorithm with multiple data types.

Comment: Polymorphism is the keyword here, Now I am thinking in same direction as you are, if you like I would like to suggest make your contracts which receive string as parameters where you can pass RAW XML then inside services you can achieve Polymorphism using Linq+XML and still return your typed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a [message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) that would inspect the incoming message on the server, and acting on it (e.g. storing it away or something).

Pablo Pialorsi has a [great blog post on how to write a message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx), step-by-step

Inspecting the message would give you access to the parameters in the raw SOAP message format.

I thought maybe a parameter inspector might be the better choice, but it would appear as though these inspectors only get their go at the parameters for any service call once those parameters have been deserialized into objects already, so that doesn't sound like a viable approach....